# Motion of a particle in a wave

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

I am having trouble solving this question. I need clarification.

> Q. Figure A (in the bottom paragraph) shows the equilibrium positions of air
> particles 1,2,3, etc. Figure B shows their positions at an instant when a longitudinal  travelling wave moves through
> air to the right. Which of the following are correct  statements  regarding particles in figure B?
>
> Options are:
>
> 1. Particles 4 is at rest at this instant
> 2. Particle 3 and 5 are moving in same direction
> 3. Particle 3 will move to the right immediately after this instant of time
> 4. Particle 7 will move to the left immediately after this instant of time
>
> Answers are -$2,3,4$

Since the particle 4 is at equilibrium position , so  velocity would be the maximum hence option A is incorrect.

However I am not able to think of the movement of other particles, it looks like 3 and 5 are at the extreme positions so they should move leftward and rightward respectively.

The wave direction is rightward so the particle 7 should move towards the right.

P.S. The question from the beginning, along with the answer choices after it, are both from this image in the link [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei8Xc.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question!

I am used to questions about standing waves, so I had to hunt for the answer to this.

I have looked at several websites, and here's my impression of what is going on.  In the animations, where the particles are all bunched up, they are *all* traveling in the direction of the wave, (they are the wave pulse) so $3,4,5$ and $9,10,11$ should all be moving to the right.  The particles in the gaps, where the concentration is lower, should be moving left, to get back to their starting places.  So I think $1,7,13$ would all be moving left.

In a traveling longitudinal wave, none of the particles end up traveling, it is only the pattern which travels.  Each individual particle oscillates in place. A particle at its equilibrium position is like a mass on a spring passing through its equilibrium position: that is the point where it has maximum velocity.

This isn't like a standing wave where particles stay stationary at node points.  None of the particles stay stationary in a traveling wave, they all oscillate.  In order for a pulse to travel to the right, new particles have to join in coming from the right, while old particles leave from the left edge, slow down, then turn around and go back, to become part of the next longitudinal pulse.

So the place of high particle concentration is a "wave crest" traveling to the right.  The central particle is moving at the wave velocity.  The particle to its left is moving slightly slower, so it will pull away, while the particle to its right is also moving slightly slower, so it will get more bunched up.  The particle left of the crest is slowing down, while the particle on the right is speeding up towards maximum, when it will get its turn as the wave crest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have few questions related to it. How can we say, that where the particles are bunched up, they are all travelling in the same direction as wave, could you please elaborate? Why should the particles in the gaps where the concentration is lower move to the left? Consider particle 6, its equilibrium position is rightward of it. In both the figures, the particle 7 are at the same postion, so what do you mean by returing back to their starting places? It would be really helpful if you clarify it thanks.

Comment: @green_32 I have added more details, hopefully that will clarify.

Comment: Be careful here.  If your answer is correct (I'm not sure it is) then it sounds to me like a complete solution to the problem.  That's not allowed here.  You might modify this in a way that orients the OP to a way of thinking about the problem.  Or you can delete the answer.